# Redirecting problem/Returning View problem in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am new to ASP.NET and to MVC as well.
The thing I am trying to do is If the NIC(int value) matches 1234567891113
I should get Verification (Another View) otherwise, It should stay on the same View.
However, after making 1 wrong entry, the URL changes and I get stuck.
Please look at the codes for better understanding

VoterController(Where I am using Conditions and want to return specific view)

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult logIn(Int64 NIC)
    {
        if (NIC == 1234567891113)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Verification");
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult Verification()
    {   

        return View();
    }
```

The View

```
    <h1> Voter Form</h1>
<form action="logIn" method="post">

 <p>Welcome to ECP Portal, Please Enter your NIC Details to Continue</p>
  <br>

 Enter Your NIC No &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input id="textsend" class="nic" type="text" name="NIC" value="" placeholder="Enter Only Numbers without dashes" size ="27" maxlength ="13" minlength ="13" onKeyUp="textBox()"/>

  </br>
  </br> 
  <input id="button" type="submit" disabled value="Next" size="50"/>

</form>
```

It gets redirected to

> http://localhost:5398/Voter
>   Whereas I want to get 
>   http://localhost:5398/Voter/Index in order for it to work.
>   Please help.
>   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Used Redirect and that solved the problem.

```
public ActionResult Authenticate(Int64 NIC)
    {
        if (NIC == 1234567891113)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Verification");
        }
        else
            return Redirect("/Voter/Index");
    }
```

However, If anyone can be kind enough to let me know a better or more efficient way, I will be obliged.
Cheers!